# Devo utilizar First depois de utilizar Open no Firedac?

Tags: delphi, firedac

Quando utilizo o FDQuery para realizar um select que retornar **n** registros, preciso utilizar o comando .First após o .Open para garantir que fique no primeiro registro?

Exemplo:

```
QryAux3.Close;
QryAux3.SQL.Text := 'Select * from Produtos';
QryAux3.Open;
QryAux3.First; //Precisa desta linha?
```

Comment: Por boa pratica sim... quase toda a gente faz. Se está a perguntar se o open já vem no first, nao tenho a certeza,  provavelmente sim, mas penso que nao deve assumir isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faz sentido utilizar o first, basta realizar qualquer consulta e observar a propriedade `RecNo` estará sempre no primeiro registro, ou seja, após o comando `Open` o cursor estará sempre no primeiro registro.

Mesmo se utilizar `Order by ASC/DESC` e isto vale para qualquer componente no Delphi, dede que o deixe com as configurações padrões.

Isto é o mesmo que:

```
vTeste := TStringList.Create;
vTeste.Clear;
```

Totalmente desnecessário.

Answer (score 2):

A procedure "First"  geralmente é usado para garantir que o conjunto de dados do dataset irá para o primeiro registro. Geralmente a procedure First é usando em While, for, foreach, não necessariamente.

Exemplo:

```
  query.Open;
  query.First;
  while not(query.oef) do
  begin
    // Alguma coisa
    query.next;
  end;
```

**Como nosso colega "Junior Moreira" disse dando query.open, automaticamente estará no primeiro registro.**

Não tem necessidade de dar First, mas já vi tive alguns situações que precisei usar a procedure First.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.First